# querySelectorAll Need to select all divs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in need of getting a working search bar for these cards (only one included in the code to save space), the js I've been using worked fine for now, but recently I had to add a new div (with class sce-all) which made it search only some of the items or actually too many from different divs and makes the other info into display:none when I search for anything from div (with class sce-e). When I try to search anything right now, it also searches from div (with class sce-e), I only need it to search from div (with class sce-tt) or it could be both, but it gives it the display:none tag currently. I tried changing up the ('.card div:nth-child(2)') in the js which is the cause of the problem it seems.
Thanks for any help

```js
const searchEl = document.querySelector('.searchbox');
const x = document.querySelectorAll('.card div:nth-child(2)');

function search(e) {
  x.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (!item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value)) {
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
}

searchEl.addEventListener("keyup", search);
```

```html
<form class='searchbox'>
  <input class="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
</form>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="cards-vid">

    <div class="video anim card">
      <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="video-wrapper-inside">
          <a href="vid.mp4"><video preload="metadata">
            <source src="vid.mp4#t=139" type="video/mp4">
          </video></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sce-all">
        <div class="sce-e"><a href="none">Link Title</a><span class="length-t">0ms</span></div>
        <div class="sce-tt">Title</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tags-and-info">
        <div class="tags"><a><span class="category-tag">Main</span></a><span class="language-edit"><a href="vid.mp4">ENG</a></span></div>
        <hr class="sce-hr">
        <div class="sce-inf">Info<span class="seperate video-seperate"></span>0h 46m<span class="seperate video-seperate"></span>2023</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you looking for this `const x = document.querySelectorAll('.sce-tt');` ?

Comment: This only changes the parent tag of the div above it so it makes .sce-all invisible and leaves the rest of the divs visible. That's why I have the .card in there also to effect the whole thing

Comment: Avoid using selectors like `:nth-child(2)`. Use classes so that you can rearrange the children without having to update all the selectors.

Comment: const x = document.querySelectorAll('.card .sce-all'); I removed the nth-child and it seems to be working with this configuration, I was trying to have a search bar that would search from only some of the divs for values and only display the cards that have that value in the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `x` to just select the `.sce-tt` divs. Then when it decides whether to hide or show the parent, use `closest('.card')` to find the containing card, rather than specifying `.parent`.

```js
const searchEl = document.querySelector('.searchbox');
const x = document.querySelectorAll('.card .sce-tt');

function search(e) {
  x.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (!item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value)) {
      item.closest(".card").style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      item.closest(".card").style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
}

searchEl.addEventListener("keyup", search);
```

```html
<form class='searchbox'>
  <input class="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
</form>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="cards-vid">

    <div class="video anim card">
      <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="video-wrapper-inside">
          <a href="vid.mp4"><video preload="metadata">
            <source src="vid.mp4#t=139" type="video/mp4">
          </video></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sce-all">
        <div class="sce-e"><a href="none">Link Title</a><span class="length-t">0ms</span></div>
        <div class="sce-tt">Title</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tags-and-info">
        <div class="tags"><a><span class="category-tag">Main</span></a><span class="language-edit"><a href="vid.mp4">ENG</a></span></div>
        <hr class="sce-hr">
        <div class="sce-inf">Info<span class="seperate video-seperate"></span>0h 46m<span class="seperate video-seperate"></span>2023</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes sir, thank you. It does work with the original item.parentElement also but with changing it to document.querySelectorAll('.card .sce-all');